# Convert c# linq query to vb.net

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-entities

I have some C# LINQ code and would like to convert it to vb.net. Can you help?

```
var userSessionId= 25;
ProjectsPerUser = db.tbProjekt.Where(s => s.tbUserProjects.Any(x => x.UserId == userSessionId)).ToList();
```

it was out of this raw sql query:

```
 ProjectsPerUser = db.Database.SqlQuery(Of tbProjekt)("SELECT * FROM [16281468_general].[dbo].[tbProjekt] WHERE Id " _
                & "IN (SELECT DISTINCT ProjectId FROM [16281468_general].[dbo].[tbUserProject] WHERE UserId = " & userSessionId & ")").ToList
```

now I want to convert it to vb.net but I have some problems with that.

That is my current try:

*tables within context: tbProjekt and tbUserProjects*

```
Dim dabcon As New production_TextEntitesContext
Dim ProjectsPerUsers As New List(Of tbProjekt)
Dim userSessionId As Integer = 111
ProjectsPerUsers = dabcon.tbProjekt.Where(Function(s) s.tbUserProjects.Any(Function(x) x.UserId = userSessionId)).ToList()
```

But, I got this error:

> Late binding operations cannot be converted to expression tree

on line `s.tbUserProjects.Any.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this would help. Just an example

```
Sub Main()
        Dim projects As New List(Of Integer)
        projects.Add(1)
        projects.Add(2)
        projects.Add(3)

        Dim users As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
        users.Add("john", 1)
        users.Add("mary", 2)


        Dim userName As String = "john"


        Dim userProjects = From p In projects
                           Join u In users On p Equals u.Value
                           Where u.Key = userName
                           Select p, u.Key

        For Each v In userProjects
            Console.WriteLine("user: {0}  project: {1}", v.Key, v.p)
        Next

        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
```

Comment: working . Can you explain why in my main post i am receiving error i mentioned?

Comment: My guess is that you should declare  ProjectsPerUsers As IQueryable(Of tbProjekt). Also when working with VB set in project properties Compile Option Strict to ON to avoid use of late binding.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have navigation properties set up, this should work as well:

```
Dim userProjects=dabcon.tbUsers.Where(Function(u) u.Key=userName).Select(Function(u) u.Projects))
```

or query syntax:

```
Dim userProjects=from u in dabcon.tbUsers
                 where u.Key=userName
                 select u.Projects
```